# How to separate API calling class in swift with Alomofire?

Tags: ios, swift, api

I want to create my own network manager class so that I could handle the errors globally like there is no internet then I can show pop-ups from that class only. I am using Alomofire for this and also want to parse the data in JSON with the help of swiftjson library. I have tried with my code but not able to pass the data from my network class to where the function is being called.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SystemConfiguration

class WebServiceHelper: NSObject {

typealias SuccessHandler = (JSON) -> Void
typealias FailureHandler = (Error) -> Void

// MARK: - Internet Connectivity

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}

// MARK: - Helper Methods

class func getWebServiceCall(_ strURL : String, isShowLoader : Bool, success : @escaping SuccessHandler, failure : @escaping FailureHandler) {
        if isConnectedToNetwork()  {

            print(strURL)

            if isShowLoader == true {

                //AppDelegate.getDelegate().showLoader()
            }

            AF.request(strURL).responseJSON { (resObj) -> Void in
                print(resObj.result)
            }
        }else {
            //CommonMethods.showAlertWithError("", strMessage: Messages.NO_NETWORK, withTarget: (AppDelegate.getDelegate().window!.rootViewController)!)
        }
    }

}
```

// calling from the controller

```
func getData() {
        WebServiceHelper.getWebServiceCall("http://3.16.229.165/webservice/getFollowingList", isShowLoader: false, success: { (responceObj) in
            
            print("success => \(responceObj)")
        }
            
        , failure: { (failureObj) in
            print("failureObj = \(failureObj)")
        })
    }
```

// API response data

```
{
    "status": false,
    "followers": false,
    "message": "You are not yet following anyone"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `success(value)`

```
AF.request(strURL).responseJSON { (resObj) -> Void in 
   switch resObj.result {
       case .success(let value):
           let res = JSON(value)
           success(res)
       case .failure(let error):
           failure(error) 
   } 
}
```

Comment: why we are using  success(resObj.result) at the end as it's working without it